# In photoshop, how can i get rid of this selected edges?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

In photoshop, when I clicked a layer, and then show like this

how can I get rid of this?

I already tried to this method --> view

but it's not working

[image]

Comment: view -> show -> show extra options ->it's not working

Comment: Click somewhere off the canvas to deselect a shape/smart object.

Answer (score 3):

Those are transform controls of the `Move Tool`. To hide them, uncheck the `Show Transform Controls` option in the top bar:

[image]

Comment: I never had transform controls... That's why I look like the guy from Akira.

Comment: Wouldnt the answer be activate a tool that is not move? @Joonas ahaaa.

Comment: @joojaa that's an option, but I think it's useful to know where this box comes from so that `move tool`  can be used with or without it